# SqlCeDataAdapter, queries trouble

Tags: sql, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I am new to SQL Server CE, and I seem to have a problem with understanding how `SqlDataAdapter` works. I am trying to connect to one DB, put the table into `DataSet`, and then load this table into second DB. It all seems pretty short when it comes to code, but I don't understand one thing. The fact that there are 2 `connectionStrings` is self-explanatory. But why in `SqlDataAdapter` we use same queries?

If I `SELECT * FROM dbName.tableName`, and fill `DataSet`with this data, why when creating new `SqlDataAdapter` I have to put the same query?

Comment: You cannot select from dbname.tablename with SQL Compact. And using datasets with SQL Compact is not recommended

Comment: you don't need the dbName in the query because your target database is specified in the SqlCeConnection (InitialCatalog property)